# What is the best clustering method to detect anomalies for data with mostly categorical data?

Tags: unsupervised-learning, clustering, algorithm-request, anomaly-detection, categorical-data

I have a dataset with about 85 columns. Out of the 85 columns, 70+ are categorical. My goal is to identify the outliers in this dataset through clustering methods as I do not have a target column.

What is the best way to approach this? Is it advisable to convert all the 70+ columns to dummies in pandas and use a clustering algorithm like DBScan?